# keras retinanet model converter to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, retinanet

I trained a model for class recognition. I used fizyr's Keras for training: [Fizyr - Keras Retinanet GitHub](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet).

I managed to finish the training with excellent results. My goal is to integrate the obtained model into android.

I tried to convert the model using this script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_retinanet.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
if __name__ == "__main__":
model = load_model("modelFINAL.h5")
   fixed_input = Input((1080,1920,3))
   fixed_model = Model(fixed_input,model(fixed_input))
   converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(fixed_model)
   tflite = converter.convert()
   # Save the model.
   with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(tflite)
```

But when I go to import the model into the android application, the application crashes.

Anyone know how to help me convert a keras .h5 model to a .tflite model?

Console output:

> 2021-10-07 12:09:17.221
> 21554-21599/org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection E/tflite: Didn't
> find op for builtin opcode 'MUL' version '5'. An older version of this
> builtin might be supported. Are you using an old TFLite binary with a
> newer model? 2021-10-07 12:09:17.221
> 21554-21599/org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection E/tflite:
> Registration failed. 2021-10-07 12:09:17.234
> 21554-21599/org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection E/AndroidRuntime:
> FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 Process:
> org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection, PID: 21554
> java.lang.AssertionError: Error occurred when initializing
> ObjectDetector: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'MUL' version '5'.
> An older version of this builtin might be supported. Are you using an
> old TFLite binary with a newer model?
>
> ```
> at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.initJniWithModelFdAndOptions(Native
> ```
>
> Method) at
> org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.access$000(ObjectDetector.java:86)
> at
> org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector$1.createHandle(ObjectDetector.java:152)
> at
> org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector$1.createHandle(ObjectDetector.java:145)
> at
> org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils$1.createHandle(TaskJniUtils.java:70)
> at
> org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromLibrary(TaskJniUtils.java:91)
> at
> org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromFdAndOptions(TaskJniUtils.java:66)
> at
> org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.createFromFileAndOptions(ObjectDetector.java:143)
> at
> org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection.MainActivity.runObjectDetection(MainActivity.kt:127)
> at
> org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection.MainActivity.access$runObjectDetection(MainActivity.kt:48)
> at
> org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection.MainActivity$setViewAndDetect$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:165)
> at
> kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
> at
> kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
> 2021-10-07 12:09:17.245
> 21554-21599/org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection I/Process: Sending
> signal. PID: 21554 SIG: 9

Comment: I think that the app crashed because the input batch size is high, is this the same input batch size in the training process?

Comment: I did the training like this: 
!keras_retinanet/bin/train.py --freeze-backbone --random-transform --weights {PRETRAINED_MODEL} --batch-size 8 --epochs 10 csv annotations.csv classes.csv
Should I change the input size when doing the conversion?

Comment: it's very hard to say what happens when you port it to Android.. first of all try an inference of the tflite model on your computer to see if the convertion worked. Then post the stacktrace of the error you get in Android.

Comment: What's the input size of your image in the training processus?

Comment: Could you please post the exception that you got in the console ??

Comment: Sure, i posted it

Comment: Please remove the answer and try to add your console output in the question ( Edit your question ) don't add the output as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you import the structural model first and then load the weights. Also, you are wrong to use the Model class. This accepts input (input_sample, output_sample)

[Keras Model](https://keras.io/api/models/model/)

Try it this way:

```
loaded_model = models.load_model(model_path.h5, backbone_name='resnet50')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(loaded_model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('name.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

In according to the method he proposes (cell 2)

[link Example](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/blob/main/examples/ResNet50RetinaNet.ipynb)

Comment: Nothing has changed